# Is the following sentence an adjective clause or an adjective phrase or a noun clause?

Tags: phrases, adjectives, parts-of-speech

> Yesterday, I attended a yoga class, **the majority of whom were men**.

Is the boldfaced part an adjective phrase or adjective clause?
I'm sure it's giving information about the **yoga class**.

> Yesterday, I attended a yoga class, the majority of **whom were men**.

I have doubts that the part after the second comma is a phrase.
I think the boldfaced part is a noun clause that is acting as the object of preposition. Is that correct?

Comment: Your two versions are awfully similar. And you may think that *whom* refers to *class*, but how? For a class **of 10**, we could understand the 10 to be students, the majority of whom (students) were men.

Comment: Both sentences are identical. Putting different parts in boldface doesn't change anything. And both sentences are incorrect. _You can attend a class_ if the class is an event, instead of a group of people. And _a class can be mostly men_ if the class is a group of people, instead of an event. But not both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In your example sentence, "the majority of whom were men" is a relative clause (i.e., an adjective clause). The subject of this clause is the noun phrase "the majority of whom," in which the prep phrase "of whom" modifies the "the majority." This type of construction is called a nominal partitive, as it conveys a relationship of partialness (i.e., "the majority" is a *part* of "whom"). In other words, the predicate of the relative clause ("were men") applies not to the antecedent of "whom" (the "yoga class") but rather to "the majority" of the class.

Incidentally, the use of the word "class" in your example sentence is slightly problematic. In the context of the main clause ("I attended the yoga class"), "class" refers to the course itself; however, in the context of the subordinate clause, "class" refers to the group of students participating in the course. This inconsistency could be rectified by replacing the main verb ("attended") with "was a member of" or by replacing the relative clause with "in which the majority of students were men."